# Getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' in python for image processing image_dataframe['image']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I am working on image classification using CNN.

[image: sample data frame]

I am using below source code for that task. I am stuck with this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' Could you please anyone guide me to solve this issue?
in path volume, the values are none please anyone can help me how I can mention the path of images
In this Code

```
image_dataframe.isnull().sum()
image_dataframe['age'].fillna((image_dataframe['age'].mean()), inplace=True)
image_dataframe.isnull().sum()
#Image Preprocessing
image_dataframe['image'] = image_dataframe['path'].map(lambda x: np.asarray(Image.open(x).resize((100,75))))
```

And, I've got this error:

[image: error]

Also, I am getting errors in this line:

[image: second error]

Comment: Looks like it fails to load a file. Please ensure that`image_dataframe['path']` has valid paths.

Comment: please see the picture that I uploaded. you may understand the error. In the ham100000 dataset matrix, there is a column named "path" which I am trying to map to columns but the values in the path column are none but I don't know how I can fill the values inside it.

Comment: According to this document https://www.ijeat.org/wp-content/uploads/papers/v9i6/E1079069520.pdf some records from this dataset are missing paths. You can drop these records with:
`image_dataframe['path'].dropna().map(lambda x: np.asarray(Image.open(x).resize((100,75))))
`

Comment: your answer worked but it is showing an error.

Comment: I think there is not any images with that address so you got that error.